# Hide .html and manage 404

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

i would like to do this mapping on my website

```
xyz.html -> on /xyz
abc.html -> on /abc
index.html -> on /
```

i wrote these rules on my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !^$ !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

but i have some issues.

- 404 error doesn't work anymore. if i browse /hello it gave me Internal Server Error
- I would like a redirect if i browse to /xyz.html -> /xyz (SEO friendly)

wanted actions:

```
/ -> serve index.html        
/abc -> serve abc.html       
/abc.html -> redirect to /abc      
/123.html -> throws 404      
/123/ -> throws 404 (now throws 500)
```

How can i do this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

#Remove .html extension
#1)redirect "/file.html" to "/file"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
#2) internally map /file to /file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.html [L]
#3) Redirect "index.html to "/"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [L,R=301]
#Internally map homepage "/" to "index.html"
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: It create a strange behavieur. If i include for example ../../file.js it goes 404 like i included just "file.js"

Comment: @FrancescoFattori You need to use base tag to fix your js  and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path . forexample if the URL path is `/file/` instead of `file.html` then your relative resources are loading from `/file/` which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this either make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.